# Spring websocket Client to Client communication

Tags: spring, stomp, spring-websocket

I have a requirement where my Websocket session should be able to communicate with each other.I am creating a Request  Response model where my Client A would send a request on a Queue on which I have multiple subscriber agents (Ag1 and Ag2). I would expect that my requests would round robin between these 2 subscribers. Unfortunately, the event is broadcasted to both the agents rather than it being a one to one communication.

**My Spring config**

```
@Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/websocket").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/queue", "/topic");
    }
```

**Client JS Code**

```
requestResponse = new RequestResponse({
    outgoingChannel : "/queue/clients",
    incomingChannel : "/topic/broadcast/clients",
    callbackFn : widget3eventHandler
},session);
```

**Agent Subscriber Code**

```
requestResponse = new RequestResponse({
    outgoingChannel : "/topic/broadcast/clients",
    incomingChannel : "/queue/clients",
    callbackFn : widget3eventHandler,
    processAll : true
},session);
```

Is this a bug in SIMP Broker or am i doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You can check [this sample chat application](https://github.com/salmar/spring-websocket-chat) if you want to know how to achieve client to client communication.